# How do I mark certain addresses as sent in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a database full of 70k names,addresses, etc. I also have a list of 30,000 addresses that orders have already been sent to.

Right now I have the following MySQL statement:

```sql
UPDATE `order_requests`
  SET `exported_sent`='sent_2012_05_07'
WHERE `request_address` IN (SELECT `request_address` FROM sent_list)
```

I feel like this should work, the only problem is that there is so much querying involved that phpMyAdmin keeps timing out. Unfortunately I can only match on things like fname, lname, address, zip, etc as the two tables are not linked by a common id or anything like that.

PS. I am working on a php script so that I don't have to manually do this again, but the person before me did it wrong, so I'm fixing the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will likely be much faster with a join

```
UPDATE `order_requests` JOIN sent_list USING(request_address) SET `exported_sent`='sent_2012_05_07';
```

Without a join, it's quite possible MySQL is reexecuting the query `SELECT request_address FROM sent_list` for each row in in `order_requests`.

Comment: It is giving me an error now: _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN sent_list USING(request_address)' at line 1_

Comment: Ensure there's an index on request_address on both tables so MySQL can choose the best one and use it.

Comment: The JOIN/SET order was the problem! I didn't do the index, but will do that for future! Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is probably timing out because of standard browser timeouts.  Have you tried running the query via the command line MySQL client?  It should not be affected by the same default timeouts.

Comment: Is that the SQL link at the top of phpMyAdmin? Where it goes | Browse | Structure | SQL | etc ?? Or is that something else?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about the command line client -- the dos prompt, or equivalent depending what OS you're on.

If you don't have it, you'll need to download and install it -- however I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Cool. I'll look into that for the future! Thanks